# Check FTP login data using bash

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, yad

I tried searching for a simple login data check for ftp connection in my bash script. I tried using wput and grep to get the output for a progress bar. Is there a way to check the login data first? I think wput doesn't support this...

Is there anybody who could help me with a good simple solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use wget to test the connection:

```
wget --spider --tries=1 --user=login --password=pass ftp://your-ftp.com/
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed to connect to ftp host"
fi
```

Or you can use ftp command:

```
echo 'exit' | ftp ftp://login:pass@your-ftp.com/
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed to connect to ftp host"
fi
```

Note: sending/piping 'exit' command to FTP to force it exit out of interactive mode.

Comment: I tried to run the command in background, `echo 'exit' | ftp ftp://login:pass@your-ftp.com/ &` How can I get the return value?

Comment: @user3006625 - return value (exit code) is stored in $? variable. 
You can do:
`echo $?`

Comment: It is better to use **PIPESTATUS[]** shell variable while checking exit status of the commands run with pipes. for here, in second example, use `[ ${PIPESTATUS[1]} -ne 0 ]` to get exact exit status of the second command.